# How to recursively iterate and map a JSON input to JPA entities?

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, entity

I have a sometimes large JSON object that comes to a spring controller. In its most basic form it looks like this:

```javascript
[{
    "OR": {
        "hash": "oxl6qxe5ns13aq07ug2t5",
        "items": [{
            "RULE": {
                "hash": "tyzq9saqs3hd5itvgv866",
                "condition": {
                    "field": "integrity",
                    "logic": "at_most",
                    "value": "5"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "OR": {
                "hash": "ahukz9s32al2nctjcm5toj",
                "items": [{
                    "RULE": {
                        "hash": "7t2trvx0npnsgn73fgxxg",
                        "condition": {
                            "field": "personalData",
                            "logic": "is_not",
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}]
```

It is a JSON array that at the root level contains OR or AND objects, which each have a property called `items`. This `items` property can contain either more AND or OR groups, or a RULE declaration.

What I want to do, is to effectively iterate this object and map it to my JPA entities `CtlgGroup` / `CtlgRule`. The `CtlgGroup` contains an identifier for whether it is an AND or OR configuration.

I have tried a variety of jackson and gson methods for mapping these and following examples for mapping pojos. Nothing has worked thus far.

This could be indefinitely deep, but I will probably set restrictions about how deep it can go for performance's sake. The Entity association is the same format as the json, Group can have more Groups as members, or Rules. I would like to map it to one object with subsequent child objects that can then be persisted to the database. Is this possible?

Comment: You probably want an inheritance hierarchy where `CtlgGroup` inherits from `CtlgRule` (or both inherit from some `AbstractRule`), with `CtlgGroup` using the composite pattern. For telling Jackson which specific subtype to create, you might want to look at [`@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)`](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-type-info-with-logical-type-name.html). The mapping shouldn't be too difficult, except that a SQL DB is probably not a great choice for working with deeply hierarchical data

Comment: For this approach to work, you'll need to make `CtlgAndGroup` and `CtlgOrGroup` separate classes. It's probably a sensible idea to use a `CtlgGroup` as a base entity and put the `items` property there, with `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance for the entire hierarchy